# converting a string in base greater than 10 in python 3

Tags: python, binary, calculation

As same as the topic, I am working on a strip to convert strings to values. 
when base is less than 10:

```
s = "" # string for example: "123", "a2b"
base = int() #2,10, 16, 32
a = len(s)
for i, j in zip(s[::-1], range(0, a)):
    x += int(i)*base**int(j)
print (x)
```

but for bases greater than 10, I realized that digits will be presented as 1, .....10, a, b, c, d, ..., j, ... My script won't work since a letter is not assigned any value. I also understand `int(s, base)` will solve my problem, but I am looking for a solution to make up my script.

Comment: You're right that you can't use `int`, but you could just look up those values in a *dictionary* mapping letter to value. For example, `import string; print(dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 10)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `zip` and `range`.

You can use a dict to convert a character to an int:

```
>>> {c:i for i,c in enumerate('0123456789abcdef')}
{'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11, 'e': 14, 'd': 13, 'f': 15, '1': 1, '0': 0, '3': 3, '2': 2, '5': 5, '4': 4, '7': 7, '6': 6, '9': 9, '8': 8}
```

As an example for base 16:

```
s = "abc"
base = 16
x = 0
hexa_table = {c:i for i,c in enumerate('0123456789abcdef')}
for i, c in enumerate(s[::-1]):
    x += hexa_table.get(c)*base**i
print(x)
# 2748
```

Which seems to be the correct result:

```
>>> int("abc", 16)
2748
```

You can also use `sum` for an even shorter code:

```
print(sum(hexa_table.get(c)*base**i for i, c in enumerate(s[::-1])))
# 2748
```

Comment: @derec: My pleasure. Feel free to accept the answer in order to show that it answered your question.